# Is "however" used correctly here?

Tags: word-usage

"I absolutely must see him, however painful it may be for me."

I feel like this version makes more sense.

"I absolutely must see him regardless of the pain."

If I'm wrong, can you explain how the first version makes sense. I thought however shows contradiction. I don't see the contradiction.

"My grandfather will certainly let me buy German clothes because he thinks it is longest-lasting. However, my grandmother will certainly let me buy French clothes because she thinks it is the most beautiful."

For this example, I don't feel like however is used properly either.

Comment: If you can ask “how painful is it?” Then you can use however painful.

Comment: It makes sense and is reasonably idiomatic.